# show Activity and five animation

Tags: android

i have develop one app in which `five` activity :: 
and sixth number activiy which name is `metaActivity`
now in
if First activity call `metaActivity`  then display animation number 1 in  `metaActivity`
if second activity call `metaActivity`  then display animation number 2 in  `metaActivity`
if third activity call `metaActivity`  then display animation number 3 in  `metaActivity`
if fourth activity call `metaActivity`  then display animation number 4 in  `metaActivity`
if fifth activity call `metaActivity`  then display animation number 5 in  `metaActivity`

at `metaActivity` how can it decide that first,second,third......  are call me and base on that fire animation 1 or 2 or 3 or etc...
now problem is i cant able to take judgement how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Here is an example with activity 3:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(“animNumber″, 3);

Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MetaActivity.class);
newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
```

And in MetaActivity:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
switch (bundle.getInt(“animNumber″)) {

case 1 :
    //Load animation 1;
    break;

case 2:
    //Load animation 2;
    break;

case 3:
    //Load animation 3;
    break;

(...)

default: 

    displayErrorMessage();
    break;
```

Comment: if i would like to pass Boolean then ?

Comment: putBoolean instead of putInt -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean)

Comment: so is it "animNumber" is same key for all five activity?

Comment: Please, take 5 seconds to test before asking... bundle.putInt(“animNumber″, 1); in activity 1, bundle.putInt(“animNumber″, 2); in activity 2, etc. so yes' that's of course the same key!